# AWS nodejs lambda function, change dynamically the value of environment variable

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am running a lambda function on AWS that takes a very long time to execute (big data).
It is exceeding the maximum 900 seconds (15 minutes) allowed in lambda, so the function is timing out.

Using context.getRemainingTimeInMillis(), I am thinking to trigger a new instance of the lambda just before getting the timeout. However, looks like there is no way to stop the execution of a lambda, once it is started, meaning that if I make any mistake, we could enter in a infinite loop and lambda would be running forever??
Anyway, to avoid this, I am thinking to set a environment variable called "stopExecution", which defaults to false, but in case for some reason I need to stop the execution, set it up to true.

Basically in my nodejs code I read the variable process.env.stopExecution. Now, my question is, the environment variables in a lambda, are dynamic? If I change the value during the execution, the lambda will read the new value and therefore stop? Or the environment variables are only read at the launch time of the function, and they keep the same value during the execution, so the only way to  read the new value is to wait for them to stop and launch them again?

Also, if some faced the same issue as myself and wants to propose a better solution, feel free.

Comment: No, obviously they are NOT dynamic. Any other lambda instance will NOT see a changed env variable. Within one single execution you can change the env variable but you should not do that, just use a "normal" global variable if you really need one. But simply use EC2 / ECS instead of shoehorning the task into lambda. If something takes longer than 15 minutes (or close to it) lambda is ill-suited.

Comment: If you face timeouts and want to invoke different lambdas, why not refactor the app and use Step Functions (https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/?step-functions.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&step-functions.sort-order=desc)?

Comment: I agree with @OleksiiDonoha, AWS Step Functions is suitable mechanism to process long running tasks by separating the processing into multiple lambda executions.

Comment: So, using Step functions, we would trigger a lambda, get the executionId, and then in another step, check regularly if the lambda is done (by its executionId), and relaunch a new instance in this case? Is more and less that the logic your are suggesting?

Comment: @fgonzalez lambda should process a "batch" of the work, size of the batch you can fine-tune for reasonable single lambda execution time. You can work with the "cursor" specifying where the last execution stopped the processing. The information can be either returned from the lambda, or stored in the external storage. Lambda response can contain an information whether processing is done, or continuation of processing from "cursor" point is needed. Step Function state machine can then decide whether to terminate the state machine, or invoke the lambda again to continue processing.

Comment: Yes this is how I end up doing. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question, though, there are many ways to have Lambdas more dynamic in nature by storing state in a DynamoDB, S3, Parameter store and have the state refreshed. However, I would not use it to solve your problem. I have personally been there before, and things do start getting complex. I would either try to perform a more map-reduce type approach (also complex, sometimes) or use an EC2 (KISS approach) that terminates after running.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the [new AWS BATCH serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/aws/new-fully-serverless-batch-computing-with-aws-batch-support-for-aws-fargate/) to execute your scripts, if you need variables try parameter store.